# Can condition number and VIF be used on a model with categorical variables?

Tags: categorical-data, multicollinearity

I am trying to test whether a model I am using has multicollinearity. The only two methods I've learned are condition numbers and variance inflation factor (VIF) to determine whether multicollinearity is present. However, all the examples I have used involved numerical variables.

Can VIF and condition numbers be used to evaluate a model with both numerical and categorical variables? If not, what is the appropriate way to assess multicollinearity in such circumstances?

Based on this question,

[Collinearity between categorical variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18084/collinearity-between-categorical-variables)

I would suspect the answer is no these two tools are not suitable, but I am uncertain since the answerer focuses on collinearity not multicollinearity.

Comment: Asked before ? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/274445/does-the-vif-make-sense-for-a-model-with-categorical-variables, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/430412/vif-for-categorical-variable-with-more-than-2-categories, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/285722/vif-doesnt-show-up-values-for-categorical-variables, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/583434/vif-but-with-a-categorical-response-variable, https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/457962/how-is-vif-calculated-for-dummy-variables,

Comment: ... https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/409529/how-is-gvif-calculated-for-categorical-variablesalso-is-there-any-other-way-to