# VIF - but with a categorical response variable?

Tags: python, categorical-data, variance-inflation-factor

I've seen a tonne of [tutorials](https://www.statology.org/dummy-variables-regression/) online for managing categorical variables in a VIF test by making binary dummy variables, but with a variable with 3 or more categories this means creating two or more new columns.

I'm currently working on a dataset where my response variable is 45 elements, equally divided into three categories.(All the rest of the variables are numerical)

Is it actually possible to do a VIF test on a dataset like this? I'd really appreciate someone pointing me in the right direction if it is.

For Context I've been following this [VIF test tutorial](https://www.statology.org/how-to-calculate-vif-in-python/), which includes:

```
from patsy import dmatrices
from statsmodels.stats.outliers_influence import variance_inflation_factor

#find design matrix for linear regression model using 'rating' as response variable 
y, X = dmatrices('rating ~ points+assists+rebounds', data=df, return_type='dataframe')

#calculate VIF for each explanatory variable
vif = pd.DataFrame()
vif['VIF'] = [variance_inflation_factor(X.values, i) for i in range(X.shape[1])]
vif['variable'] = X.columns

#view VIF for each explanatory variable 
vif
```

Comment: If you look at the formula for VIF, you'll see that it doesn't involve the response variable (though its interpretation as a relative increase in variance is lost).

Comment: @JohnMadden I'm not particularly brilliant at maths, but I've just updated my question to include the VIF tutorial I was following. It included a response variable. I tried reading the VIF documentation for python but I couldn't really make sense of it.

Would this also mean other multicollinearity stuff like visualisations should leave it out as well?

Comment: No need to be brilliant at maths: look at your code. The variable y is not used.

Comment: VIF is a (crude) way to analyze correlations among the *explanatory* variables.  Its calculation has nothing to do with the response variable.